# How does one connect with another machine with IP address?

Tags: java, sockets

So I've been learning Java Sockets for some time now, and all my codes are tested basically with a localhost (my own computer).

I was wondering if say I have another machine in another country, does the simple client-server connection still work? (My codes are peer-to-peer connection).

Is it that simple with just IP address and Port?

Sorry this question seems weird but back in the days when I was playing online games, simply putting "connect 'ip address' " didn't always work.

Comment: *does the simple client-server connection still work?* **Yes**, but *only* if the machine is (publicly) reachable (or you have some kind of vpn).

Comment: *Is it just that simple* -  From a high level, yeah, pretty much... Of course, not all IP addresses are accessible and firewall rules block most ports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if say I have another machine in another country, does the simple client-server connection still work?

Possibly yes, possibly no.

> Is it that simple with just IP address and Port?

Possibly yes, possibly no.

If the IP address is a public IP address, AND there are no firewall issues, then it should work.  But that is a BIG IF ......

- If the remote IP address you are trying to connect to is not a public IP address, then there is no way that packets can be routed to it.  No connection is possible.
- If there are firewalls between your machine and the remote IP, they need to let packet for that IP / protocol / port through, otherwise connections will fail.

IMO, you would be better off doing some basic research  / reading on how IP-based networking works before you ask questions like this.

---

> (My codes are peer-to-peer connection).

That is at the next level up the networking stack.  Peer-to-peer is implemented on top of transport-level protocols like TCP/IP and UDP/IP.  If the transport level doesn't work, then application level protocols won't either.